# How do I scrape this data? (textarea, aw box)

Tags: textbox, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I am trying to scrape the [zipcode data](http://proximityone.com/acs0913_zips.htm) from this page. However, the HTML element is just a text area. The AW box prevents me from copying more than one cell as well. How can I scrape the data programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zipcode data you see in the text area is available in a CSV format directly here: http://proximityone.com/countytrends/usbyzip0913.csv.